# ASP.NET ejecutar metodo a travez de AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net, razor

Hola estoy aprendiendo a usar AJAX en ASP NET, quiero ejecutar un método a traves de js, pero no estoy seguro como referenciarlo,el metodo que deseo est aen mi controlador pero cuando le doy la ruta no me dice que no encuentra nada.

```html
@model PCotiza_compras.Models.Departments
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Kyo_2";

}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div id="Content"></div>
<input type="button" name="name" value="try" onclick="DepListQuery()" />

<script>

    function DepListQuery() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../../Controllers/HomeController/.GetData()', //aquí no sé si estoy bien D:
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                    
                $("#Content").text(response.d);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Y este es el método en mi controller

```html
 [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Kyo2()
        {
          

                return View();


        }// End Get/kyo 2

        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetData()
        {
            return "This string is from Code behind";
        }
```

Muchas grácias a todos por su ayuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, en tu backend:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData()
{
    return "This string is from Code behind";
}
```

Por:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    return Content("This string is from Code behind");
}
```

Ahora, en el frontend, en tu JavaScript, reemplaza:

```
url: '../../Controllers/HomeController/.GetData()'
```

Por:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetData","Home")'
```

Ten en mente que usar un AJAX `type: 'POST'` va con un [HttpPost] en el controlador.

Al emplear un action con el atributo [HttpGet] en el controlador, hace que un AJAX sea `type: 'GET'`

**Edición**

Reemplaza:

```
$("#Content").text(response.d);
```

Por:

```
$("#Content").text(response);
```

Motivo:

Estás obteniendo un string directo por lo que la propiedad "d" está sin definición.

Finalmente, te sugiero que lleves unas clases en https://mva.microsoft.com sobre ASP.net MVC, de la misma manera, aquí te dejo un workshop que realizamos con la hermandad de StackOverflow en Español: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY el código de aquel proyecto se encuentra en GitHub en la descripción del video.

Comment: Hola funcionó ya estoy recibiendo el return como respuesta, pero aún no consigo pasar la respuesta y poder tirarla en un alert. Grácias por los links, sin duda lo checo y me suscribo ;D

Comment: De nada bro, aprende y comparte :D así entre todos le vamos con todo el power 2.0!!! Respuesta editada por cierto. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

En la url sólo se coloca el nombre del controlador SIN la palabra controller. También le quitas el "." y el "()" así como se ve a continuación:

```
url: '../../Controllers/Home/GetData'
```

Comment: si ya he intentado esto que me sugieres, alguien en mi trabajo me dijo que tratara con el punto dado a que "GETDATA" es un método, si lo pongo como me dices no lo encuentra igual :S